# BLE and Bluetooth gamepad options for Oculus

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, oculus, gamecontroller, gamepad-api

I'm planning to build a mobile app that sends over BLE a joystick commands with HID over GATT.

Does Oculus external gamepad option will be able to connect to it?
or it works only with Bluetooth?? therefore BLE won't work?

I would appreciate if you could point me to similar examples.

Thanks

Comment: working on the similar project, have you got any progress? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57780293/debugging-ble-hid-device

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oculus doesn't support BLE (Bluetooth low energy) controllers!!!

Oculus supports only:

**Samsung Gear VR Controller**

The Gear VR Controller orientation-tracked input device is the primary Gear VR controller going forward. We recommend that developers take advantage of its capabilities if it makes sense to do so with your application or game.

**Oculus Go Controller**

The Oculus Go Controller is the orientation-tracked input device for the Go.

**Bluetooth Gamepad**

Bluetooth gamepads are also supported. However, not all brands have been tested for compliance. Developers should perform appropriate due diligence for key code compatibility when utilizing gamepad input in their application.

A gamepad is necessary for testing the sample applications which come with this release.

Compatible gamepads must have the following features:

Wireless Bluetooth connection (BT3.0)

Compatible with Android devices

Start and Select buttons

Typical controls include:

One Analog Stick
Action Button (4)
Trigger Button (2)

source: https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/mobilesdk/latest/concepts/mobile-reqs/

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use HID over GATT with BLE to control Oculus. At least last time I tried the game Smash Hit with a standard BLE mouse the mouse button did the same thing as the oculus built in button.

Comment: Do you succeded to pair yours BLE mouse through Oculus App -> Pair new Gamepad option? or you paired in some other way?

Comment: Are you sure it was BLE and not regular Bluetooth?

Comment: Yes it is definitely BLE. Just pair from Bluetooth settings and activate the "use as input device" switch.

Comment: Yes it is definitely BLE. Just pair from Bluetooth settings and activate the "use as input device" switch.