# Debugging BLE HID device

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, hid

I'm trying to make an Android application for Android Things running on raspberry pi that takes USB joystick inputs (including DJI Mavic controller) and passes it over BLE HID as a gamepad.

Windows, Oculus Quest and Mac all recognize it as a gamepad, but when I try to connect to it, they connect and disconnect right away. I'm not sure why

Is there any tool on any OS that logs the BLE HID pairing process to find out what went wrong?

https://github.com/darvin/USBMavicBLEHIDAndroidThing/blob/master/app/src/main/java/jp/kshoji/blehid/HidPeripheral.java

Comment: Have you tried to look at an hci log?

Comment: Hci log? On the device that connects to my device? How?